# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined? while calculate total

Tags: angularjs

i want to find total buying price. $scope.salereports is my json. it consist of products sub array.it contains fields brice,quantity.

I write this code

```
$scope.BuyingAmount=function(){
 var buyamount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<$scope.salereports.products.length; i++){
     item=$scope.salereports.products[i]
    buyamount+=(item.brice*item.qty)
}
console.log(buyamount)
return buyamount;
}
```

i got the error like this. please tell me how to remove this.

```
angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.BuyingAmount (EmpController.js:891)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:227)
at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (angular.js:14345)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15888)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
at done (angular.js:10589)
at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728)
```

this is my json result:

```
Resource
$$hashKey:"object:15"
__v:0
_id:"5716fe9ef93044a01183dd29"
createdat:"2016-04-20T03:59:26.820Z"
customername:"Agarwal"
customerno:"989987987"
discamount:90
discount:20
grandtot:360
isDeleted:false
modifiedat:"2016-04-20T03:59:26.820Z"
ordernumber:"1112121"
products:Array[1]
0:Object
$$hashKey:"object:19"
_id:"5712257366dfa48c16d481d6"
bprice:100
created:"2016-04-20T03:59:26.822Z"
productname:"bata"
qty:3
size:7
sprice:150
__proto__:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
soldby:"admin"
```

Comment: Make sure `$scope.salereports.products` contains value (array)!

Comment: what is your json result ??

Comment: The error clearly states `salereports` is undefined. Debug and figure out why it's undefined. we can't do that with the code provided

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes it contains products. i update the question. check once

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's undefined. The error message proves it. Read the error message. My guess is that you're trying to access your data before it's actually returned by your resource.

Comment: yes. your are right. how to achieve this. please give me any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the answer

```
$scope.BuyingAmount=function(){
    var buyamount = 0;
if ($scope.salereports !==undefined) {
    for(var i = 0; i<$scope.salereports.length; i++){
    for (var j=0;j<$scope.salereports[i].products.length;j++){

      item=$scope.salereports[i].products[j]

      buyamount=item.bprice*item.qty+buyamount;

}
}
            }    
console.log(buyamount)
return buyamount;
}
```

Comment: is it the same... or very similar to my answer?  if so, you are supposed to upvote my answer and/or even accept it as the answer... it is the whole point of StackOverflow.  maybe the final way is to have 2 level of nesting but my answer is at least pointing at what the issue is

Answer (score 3):

What if you don't yet have the values for `salereports` (say, if it is being fetched by a service), and the function is already doing the calculations.  So you should have something like:

```
$scope.BuyingAmount = function() {
  var buyamount = 0;
  if ($scope.salereports !== undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.salereports.products.length; i++) {
      item = $scope.salereports.products[i]
      buyamount += (item.brice * item.qty)
    }
  }
  console.log(buyamount)
  return buyamount;
}
```

You also can use in the HTML,

```
<div ng-if="salereports !== undefined">
  {{ BuyingAmount() }}
</div>
```

(assuming your "no value" is `undefined` (if you never set it earlier).  Or if it is `null`, then you can just use it instead.  Or, just use `if ($scope.salereports) { ... }`

Comment: if($scope.salereports.products.length !==undefined){                                   // code not excuting//  }

Comment: `if ($scope.salereports !== undefined)`

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion i got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.BuyingAmount=function(){
 var buyamount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<$scope.salereports.products.length; i++){
     buyamount+=$scope.salereports.products[i].brice * $scope.salereports.products[i].quantity; 
}
console.log(buyamount)
return buyamount;
}
```